# Unable to catch ElasticSearch Connection Error

Tags: django, elasticsearch

I have a model that looks like this:

```
class Topic(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50, unique=True)

    def indexing(self):
    try:
        connections.create_connection()

        obj = TopicIndex(
            meta={'id': self.id},
            name=self.name,
        )
        obj.save()
        return obj.to_dict(include_meta=True)

    except ConnectionError:
        raise ValidationError("Something is wrong.")
```

Whenever a new Topic is saved, it also saves it into ElasticSearch. However, let's say ElasticSearch is down. If I save a new Topic, I'll start getting errors like this:

> elasticsearch.exceptions.ConnectionError:
>   ConnectionError(: Failed to establish a new connection: [WinError 10061] No
>   connection could be made because the target machine actively refused
>   it)

The error makes sense, however, I never catch it. "Something is wrong." never gets displayed. Instead, a connection tries to be made over and over again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to catch the `elasticsearch`'s exception class as,

```
from elasticsearch.exceptions import ConnectionError as ElasticConnectionError


class Topic(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50, unique=True)

    def indexing(self):
        try:
            # your try clause
        except ElasticConnectionError:
            raise ValidationError("Something is wrong.")
```

In your case, you were catching the Python's built-in [**`ConnectionError`**](https://docs.python.org/3/library/exceptions.html#ConnectionError) exception

Comment: Is there a way to limit the number of connection retries?

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't know